# How to handle gjs error parsing clusterplatform option?

Tags: centos7, gnome, gjs

I am using gjs-1.52.5 to split GATE macro for multi-core computation with condor HPC platform. I follow the guide from openGATE instruction of gjs from here:
https://opengate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_use_gate_on_a_cluster.html
But there is always an error like following:

```
gjs -numberofsplits 5 -c condor -condorscript /home/goldan/GATE/ClusterP/LinesSource7-condor.script  LinesSource7.mac

(gjs:27315): Gjs-ERROR **: 12:37:48.562: option parsing failed: Error parsing option -c
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have no idea about where is the problem with option -c, any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are invoking `/usr/bin/gjs` which is an entirely different program and not the GATE Job Splitter. Check your `PATH` environment variable.